# Toshiba ACE /4690 POS integration alternatives

Tags: point-of-sale

we are in a retail business and we are using OMNICO agile data solutions for trickling and parsing the TLOG data generated by Toshiba 4690 POS system on a near real-time basis. Unfortunately the OMNICO company went bankrupt and we are looking for alternatives to it. What are some of the alternative software for integrating Store POS tlog data to the backend systems (other than DIF).

Thanks,
Ram.

We know DIF is approved by Toshiba for integrating the same but we are looking for independent alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with RedList Solutions. Their RIO product (springboot application) is capable of parsing and transmitting TLOG from stores to enterprise DCs/cloud.
Primary effort will be around including custom strings to RIO.

Please let me know if you need more details. I don't work for Red-List solutions but we are in the same boat due to Omnico and we have done a successful POC with them.

Comment: Thank you so much Rachit. We are working with Toshiba as well directly. But this is a good tool and I will be looking into this to map out the capabilities. Greatly appreciate your response. 

Thanks.

Comment: Its a pleasure. Also I missed to add this on my previous comment but if you got an in-house development team then you can also try using apache-daffodil libraries (open source) for the transformation.